# (spring source code)when is AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator class registered to beanPostProcessors in spring context

Tags: java, spring

In spring framework source code,class `AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator` is the main role that response to create proxy for target bean. Of course, the class has implemented `InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor` interface,so spring will execute the `postProcessBeforeInstantiation` method then create a proxy bean for target bean.It is ok but in `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.class`

```
protected Object applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(Class<?> beanClass, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {

    for (BeanPostProcessor bp : getBeanPostProcessors()) {
        if (bp instanceof InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor) {
            InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor ibp = (InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor) bp;
            Object result = ibp.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(beanClass, beanName);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`getBeanPostProcessors()` method will get all BeanPostProcessors that have register in spring context.
So the question is

## when was AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator added to `List<BeanPostProcessor>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an access to spring source code right now, so I'll provide a general explanation.

All bean post processors are just regular beans defined in Spring. When you plug the support for one module or another (in particular to AOP) in your XML, spring will scan all the sources (XML, Java config, or maybe specifying a namespace, etc.), find all the Beans (parse and load) and create BeanDefinition (metadata that describes the bean) out of them - one for each bean.

During this stage, bean post processors are still regular Spring driven classes.

But then, spring will create beans out of bean definitions. And before doing this, spring says like "Ok, this bean is a BeanPostProcessor, so I'll put it aside and will use by myself for my internal purposes".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank Mark Bramnik for reminding me.In `AbstractApplicationContext`,`refresh` method ,there is a method:

```
registerBeanPostProcessors(beanFactory);
```

in `PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate` class,there is implemention to register the bean post processors.

```
// Now, register all regular BeanPostProcessors.
    List<BeanPostProcessor> nonOrderedPostProcessors = new ArrayList<BeanPostProcessor>();
    for (String ppName : nonOrderedPostProcessorNames) {
        BeanPostProcessor pp = beanFactory.getBean(ppName, BeanPostProcessor.class);
        nonOrderedPostProcessors.add(pp);
        if (pp instanceof MergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessor) {
            internalPostProcessors.add(pp);
        }
    }
    **registerBeanPostProcessors(beanFactory, nonOrderedPostProcessors);**
```

this implementation consider the postProcessor that implement `PriorityOrdered` or **Ordered** interface.